# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type application/json

Tags: java, json, jersey-2.0

I'm getting the following error in my logs:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
Grave: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class com.sample.MyDTO, genericType=class com.sample.MyDTO.
```

In general, it is caused by the lack of registered `MessageBodyWriter` but in my case, I do have the `jersey-media-proxy` JAR on the classpath (with all its dependencies). If that helps debugging, I confirm that the configure method of the `MoxyJsonFeature` is called when my web application is deployed.

I precise I'm using Jersey v2.21. My web application is deployed on Tomcat 8.0.26.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Mickael

Comment: After some playing around, the only way I was able to reproduce the problem was by _not_ having a no-arg constructor _and_ a constructor with an arg in the DTO class. Is this the case with your DTO class?

Comment: I have both a default and not-default constructor.

Comment: That's very weird. It's the first time I see this issue. I used Jersey with Moxy for a long time without any issue.

Comment: I don't know, try switching to `jersey-media-json-jackson` see it the problem persists. Just to see if it is a MOXy issue. You'll need to register `JacksonFeature` if you don't remove MOXy from the classpath

Comment: @peeskillet It works with Jackson. Looks like an issue with MOXy.

Comment: @peeskillet I created an issue on JIRA (see https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2963).

Answer (score 4):

It took me a while to figure it out, but you let me to the solution. It appears that for Moxy to work you need use a:

1. Default constructor
2. Setter methods

for every resource